# On-demand IEnumerable binding to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've got a potentially rather large list of objects I'd like to bind to a ListBox in WPF.  However, I'd like to have the List load itself incrementally.  How can I bind  a ListBox to an IEnumerable that loads itself on-demand in such a way that the listbox only tries to enumerate as much as it needs for the display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF ListBox's use a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) as the layout control for its items. You can set the VirtualizingStackPanel to only load items as needed with the following XAML:

```
<ListBox 
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    ItemSource="..."
    />
```

Comment: In Silverlight, I saw that `IsVirtualizing` property is readonly. How about it?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the list in a database - maybe an in-memory one - and then retrieve the needed chunk in your IEnumerable using LINQ.

Comment: That's a pretty good suggestion, except I'm trying to avoid having everything in memory, not just in the UI.

Comment: Then you can store the data in a full-blown database and retrieve it as needed with LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

With winform, "virtual mode" - but AFAIK, this isn't the same in WPF.
You could see [this MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6d8e6f19-538a-4808-a5b0-4f6969041129/) post.

I largely agree with Drew Marsh - let the user filter the data, rather than scroll through it.

Comment: That's not the right approach for this app.  The user will still be able to filter ans sort, but it will be constrained by a graph structure that has to remain intact.